# Multiple integrals involving product of gamma functions

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, gamma-function

The following integral was posted a few days back on Integrals and Series forum:
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dk_1\,dk_2\,dk_3}{1-\frac{1}{3}\left(\cos k_1+\cos k_2+ \cos k_3\right)}=\frac{\sqrt{6}}{4}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{24}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{24}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{7}{24}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{11}{24}\right)$$

I am curious if there is a closed form solution for:

$$\int_{\large[0,2\pi]^n} \frac{dk_1\,dk_2\,dk_3\,\cdots \,dk_n}{1-\frac{1}{n}\left(\cos k_1+\cos k_2+\cos k_3+\cdots +\cos k_n\right)}$$

---

Since $\left|\dfrac{\cos k_1 + \cos k_2 + \cos k_3}{3}\right|<1$,

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dk_1\,dk_2\,dk_3}{1 - \frac 1 3 \left( \cos k_1 + \cos k_2 + \cos k_3 \right)}$$
$$=8\int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \frac{dk_1\,dk_2\,dk_3}{1 - \frac 1 3 \left( \cos k_1 + \cos k_2 + \cos k_3 \right)}$$
$$=8\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^n} \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \left( \cos k_1 + \cos k_2 + \cos k_3 \right)^n\,dk_1\,dk_2\,dk_3 $$

We can ignore the odd values of $n$ as the integral is zero for them. Also, for even values of $n$, the exponents of cosines in the expansion of $\left( \cos k_1 + \cos k_2 + \cos k_3 \right)^{2n}$ must be even. Hence, from multinomial therem, we can write:

$$8\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\,\,\sum_{m_1+m_2+m_3=n} \frac{1}{3^{2n}}\frac{(2n)!}{(2m_1)! (2m_2)! (2m_3)!} \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \cos^{2m_1}k_1\cos^{2m_2}k_2 \cos^{2m_3}k_3\,dk_1\,dk_2\,dk_3$$

$$ = 16\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\,\,\sum_{m_1+m_2+m_3=n} \frac{1}{3^{2n}}\frac{(2n)!}{(2m_1)! (2m_2)! (2m_3)!} \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^{2m_1}k_1\cos^{2m_2}k_2 \cos^{2m_3}k_3\,dk_1\,dk_2\,dk_3$$

Using the result: $\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^{2k}x\,dx=\frac{(2k)!}{4^k (k!)^2}\frac{\pi}{2}$, the integral is,

$$2\pi^3 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\,\,\sum_{m_1+m_2+m_3=n} \frac{1}{36^n}\frac{(2n)!}{(m_1!)^2 (m_2!)^2 (m_3!)^2}$$

I am stuck here.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Some similar integrals ( $\sf\mbox{Watson/Van Peype Triple Integrals}$ ) are in the
[Najin book](http://www.amazon.com/Inside-Interesting-Integrals-Substitutions-Undergraduate/dp/1493912763/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1419122698&sr=8-1&keywords=nahin).

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer to the question, **but** it is too long for a comment. Here is a piece of information that I know about the integral that might help you to evaluate it. The integral above is known as one of the three of the Watson/van Peype Triple Integrals:
\begin{align}
I_1&=\frac{1}{\pi^3}\int_0^\pi\int_0^\pi\int_0^\pi\frac{\mathrm dx\;\mathrm dy\;\mathrm dz\;}{1-\cos x \cos y \cos z}\\[7pt]
I_2&=\frac{1}{\pi^3}\int_0^\pi\int_0^\pi\int_0^\pi\frac{\mathrm dx\;\mathrm dy\;\mathrm dz\;}{3-\cos x \cos y -\cos x \cos z -\cos y \cos z }\\[7pt]
I_3&=\frac{1}{\pi^3}\int_0^\pi\int_0^\pi\int_0^\pi\frac{\mathrm dx\;\mathrm dy\;\mathrm dz\;}{3-\cos x -\cos y -\cos z }
\end{align}
These three integrals first appeared in a paper published by W. F. van Peype, “*Zur Theorie der Magnetischen Anisotropic Kubischer Kristalle Beim Absoluten Nullpunkt*,” Physica, June 1938, pp. 465–482. That is, van Peype was studying magnetic behavior in certain cubic crystalline lattice structures at very low temperatures (low means near absolute zero). The Watson/van Peype integrals turn-up not only in the physics of frozen magnetic crystals, but also in the pure mathematics of random walks. You can find a complete discussion of both the history and the mathematics of the integrals in I. J. Zucker, “*70+ Years of the Watson Integrals*,” Journal of Statistical Physics, November 2011, pp. 591–612.

The evaluation of these three integrals can be found in a paper published by G. N. Watson, “*Three Triple Integrals*,” Quarterly Journal of Mathematics, 1939, pp. 266–276. Here are the closed forms of the three integrals:
\begin{align}
I_1&=\frac{\Gamma^4\!\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{4\pi^3}\\[7pt]
I_2&=\frac{3\Gamma^6\!\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}{2^{14/3}\pi^4}\\[7pt]
I_3&=\frac{\Gamma\!\left(\frac{1}{24}\right)\Gamma\!\left(\frac{5}{24}\right)\Gamma\!\left(\frac{7}{24}\right)\Gamma\!\left(\frac{11}{24}\right)}{16\sqrt{6}\,\pi^3}
\end{align}
The evaluation of these three integrals can also be found in [Watson's Triple Integrals - Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WatsonsTripleIntegrals.html). The evaluation of general form of Watson's integrals
\begin{align}
W_1(n_1)&=\frac{1}{\pi^3}\int_0^\pi\int_0^\pi\int_0^\pi\frac{\mathrm dx\;\mathrm dy\;\mathrm dz\;}{1-\frac{n_1}{3}(\cos x \cos y +\cos x \cos z +\cos y \cos z )}\\[7pt]
W_2(n_2)&=\frac{1}{\pi^3}\int_0^\pi\int_0^\pi\int_0^\pi\frac{\mathrm dx\;\mathrm dy\;\mathrm dz\;}{1-\frac{n_2}{3}(\cos x +\cos y +\cos z )}
\end{align}
can be found in a paper published by G. S. Joyce and I. J. Zucker, “[*On The Evaluation of Generalized Watson Integrals*](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2005-133-01/S0002-9939-04-07447-7/S0002-9939-04-07447-7.pdf)”.

Comment: Some similar integrals ( $\sf\mbox{Watson/Van Peype Triple Integrals}$ ) are in the
[Najin book](http://www.amazon.com/Inside-Interesting-Integrals-Substitutions-Undergraduate/dp/1493912763/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1419122698&sr=8-1&keywords=nahin).

Answer (score 1):

I have found the following result:
Take the inverse Laplace transform of
$$
I_n(a)=\int_{\large[0,2\pi]^n} \frac{dk_1\,dk_2\,dk_3\,\cdots \,dk_n}{a-\frac{1}{n}\left(\cos k_1+\cos k_2+\cos k_3+\cdots +\cos k_n\right)}
$$
with respect to $a$. This gives
$$
\mathcal{L}^{-1}_{a \to s}[I_n(a)] = \int_{\large[0,2\pi]^n} \exp\left(\frac{s}{n}\left(\sum_{l=1}^n \cos(k_l)\right)\right) \;dk_1 \cdots d
k_n$$
which is also
$$
\mathcal{L}^{-1}_{a \to s}[I_n(a)] = \prod_{l=1}^n \int_0^{2\pi}\exp\left(\frac{s \cos(k_l)}{n}\right) \; dk_l
$$
So the integrals are seperable
$$
\mathcal{L}^{-1}_{a \to s}[I_n(a)]= \left(\int_0^{2\pi} e^{s\cos(x)/n}\; dx\right)^n
$$
$$
\mathcal{L}^{-1}_{a \to s}[I_n(a)]= \left(2\pi I_0\left(\frac{s}{n}\right)\right)^n
$$
and taking the Laplace transform of both sides gives
$$
I_n(a) = \int_0^\infty  \left(2\pi I_0\left(\frac{s}{n}\right)\right)^n e^{-s a} \; ds
$$
where $I_0(x)$ is a Bessel function, so
$$
I_n = \int_0^\infty  \left(2\pi I_0\left(\frac{s}{n}\right)\right)^n e^{-s} \; ds
$$

it indeed seems that
$$
\int_0^\infty  \left(2\pi I_0\left(\frac{s}{3}\right)\right)^3 e^{-s} \; ds = \frac{\sqrt{6}}{4}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{24}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{24}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{7}{24}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{11}{24}\right)
$$

this solution seems to relate to the [elliptic integral singular value](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegralSingularValue.html) $K(k_6)$ in the link. It seems that $I_1$ and $I_2$ don't converge, but $I_4$ and $I_5$ and higher seem to numerically.